# How to prove the concurrency of these lines?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Suppose that in $\Delta ABC$ we take a point $D$ on $BC$ such that the incircles of $\Delta ACD$ and $\Delta ABD$ are tangent at a point.Now suppose that points $H$ and $I$ are defined on segments $AC$ and $AB$ in the same manner as $D$ was defined on $BC$ above. How can i prove that lines $AD,BH,CI$ are concurrent ?

**My attempt:**
[image]

I've applied Ceva's Theorem and by that I've got :$$ \cfrac{AH \cdot CD \cdot BI}{HC \cdot DB \cdot AI}=1$$

And after that I haven't really made so much progress,some of the thoughts I had was to prove that $AH=AI$ ,$CD=HC$ and $BI=DB$.

But from that i don't simple know how to proceed,for example if we consider$AI=AH$,we see that we have to prove that $IS=UH$ but how to prove that?Same reasoning goes for the other equalities..

Also if you would adopt my approach how would you continue ?

(I am not asking to post solutions only using this approach,but just any hint)

Comment: Their intersection is the [Gergonne point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Gergonne_triangle_and_point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that
$$BD-DC=BT_2-CZ=BP-CV=AB-AC.$$
Since $BD+DC=BC$, we have
$$BD=\frac{BC+AB-AC}2,DC=\frac{BC+AC-AB}{2}.$$
By symmetry we see what you are looking for: $$BD=BI, CD=CH,AI=AH.$$

**Remark**: $D,I,H$ are tangent points of the incircle of $\triangle ABC$ to the respective sides.

Comment: "It's easy to see that (...)" no it's not for me,can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: $BD=BT_2+DT_2$, $DC=DZ+CZ$, and $DT_2=DZ(=DG)$ since the incircles are tangent at $G$.

Comment: I have a question:Does the condition that $BD=BI ,CD=CH,AI=AH$ imply that $D,I,H$ are tangent points of the incircle of $ \Delta ABC $?

Comment: Yes, because they uniquely determine the length of each segment and that the tangent points of the incircles share the same properties.

Comment: How would I prove it by contradiction (sorry if i abuse your time,this is indeed the last question i ask you,thanks again)?

Comment: What is "it", "concurrency" or "tangent points"? Actually, either way I don't know how to prove "it" by contradiction since this seems more natural to me.

Comment: But one could argue that for any other points $X,Y,Z$ that lie on sides $AB,BC,AC$ respectively , if we have $BX=BY$,$AX=AZ$,$CZ=CY$,then $X,Y,Z$ are "incircle" points...but that can't be true of course or is it ?

Comment: Of course it is. Because the three equalities **imply** that $BX=\dfrac{BC+BA-AC}{2}$ and the three tangent points of the incircle obviously satisfy those inequality.